# jquery.js: Uncaught ReferenceError: connect is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I run this code on a website with a database, this interacts with the ambiance.js , jquery.js (3.2.1) and socket.js but I believe this requires some other dependency that I omitted.

[image: google chrome console]

```
var SOCKET = null;
var user = null;

 $(document).ready(function() {

    connect();
});

function request(msg)
{ 
var m=msg;
if(m.type == 'aMessage')
   {
       console.log(m.msg);   
   }
  function connect()
    { 
       if(!SOCKET)
       { 
           var hash = getCookie('hash');
           if (hash == '')
           {
               $.ambiance({message: 'Please login!'});
           }
           else
           {
               $.ambiance({message: 'Connecting to server..', type: 'success'});                  
           }
           SOCKET = io(':4095');
           SOCKET.on('connect', function(msg)
          {
               if(hash != '')
               {
                   $.ambiance({message: 'Connected', type: 'success'});
               }
               SOCKET.emit('hash', {
                   hash: hash
               });
          });
           SOCKET.on('connect_error', function(msg){
               $.ambiance({message: 'Connection lost', type: 'error'});
           });

           SOCKET.on('request', function(msg){
               request(msg);
           });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you just define a function inside a function?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you created the `connect()` function inside the request function (which wasn't called yet):

[image]

Just move it outside and it should work.

[image]